# Low rank vector bundles on hypersurfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

As far as I know, it is still unknown whether there exists a (holomorphic) indecomposable vector bundle of rank $r$ on $\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ with $n\geq 6$ and $1<r< n-1$. What is the situation for hypersurfaces? Does anyone know a smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}_{\mathbb{C}}$ ($n> 6$) carrying an indecomposable vector bundle of rank $r$ with $1<r< n-1$?

**Edit**: As pointed out by Dragon, I overlooked the spinor bundles on 6-dimensional quadrics, so let me assume $n>6$.

Answer (score 6):

What about the paper by GIORGIO OTTAVIANI on spinor bundles on quadrics? There is a rank 4 spinor bundle on a dimension 6 quadric, unless I am mistaken?

Comment: The article probably being https://www.ams.org/tran/1988-307-01/S0002-9947-1988-0936818-5/S0002-9947-1988-0936818-5.pdf, right?

Comment: You are right, the spinor bundles on quadrics give an example for $n=6$. I edit.